# Python: Additional records will not append to file

Tags: python, append

When displaying all invoice orders, the only invoice record that will display is option 1 for file write, while all additional invoice records using option 2 on append are absent. How should I got about ensuring each additional invoice record will also be displayed when choosing option 3. (I am aware of my mediocre coding)

```
run_again = 'y'

while run_again == 'y':
    widget = 10.55
    gidget = 7.30
    doodad = 5.25
    print('1 - Create a new Invoice Order')
    print('2 - Add an additional Invoice Order')
    print('3 - Display all Invoice Orders')
    print('4 - QUIT')
    choice = int(input('Enter 1,2,3, or 4: '))
    if (choice == 1):
                 invoice_file = open('invoices.txt', 'w')
                 ID = input('1 of 4 - Enter customer ID: ')
                 numwidgets = int(input('2 of 4 - Enter number of Widgets'
                                        ' Ordered @ $10.55 each: '))
                 numgidgets = int(input('3 of 4 - Enter number of Gidgets'
                                        '(Ordered @ $7.50 each): '))
                 numdoodads = int(input('4 of 4 - Enter number of Doodads'
                                        '(Ordered @ $5.25 each: '))
                 invoice_file.write(ID + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numwidgets) + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numgidgets) + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numdoodads) + '\n')

                 invoice_file.close()
                 print('Data has been added to file invoices.txt')

    if (choice == 2):
                 invoice_file = open('invoices.txt', 'a')
                 ID = input('1 of 4 - Enter customer ID: ')
                 numwidgets = int(input('2 of 4 - Enter number of Widgets'
                                        ' Ordered @ $10.55 each: '))
                 numgidgets = int(input('3 of 4 - Enter number of Gidgets'
                                        '(Ordered @ $7.50 each): '))
                 numdoodads = int(input('4 of 4 - Enter number of Doodads'
                                        '(Ordered @ $5.25 each: '))
                 invoice_file.write(ID + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numwidgets) + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numgidgets) + '\n')
                 invoice_file.write(str(numdoodads) + '\n')

                 invoice_file.close()
                 print('Data has been added to file invoices.txt')     
    if (choice == 3):
                 invoice_file = open('invoices.txt', 'r')
                 ID = invoice_file.readline()
                 numwidgets = float(invoice_file.readline())
                 numgidgets = float(invoice_file.readline())
                 numdoodads = float(invoice_file.readline())
                 records = 0
                 records += 1
                 widgettotal = widget * numwidgets
                 gidgettotal = gidget * numgidgets
                 doodadtotal = doodad * numdoodads
                 invoicetotal = widgettotal + gidgettotal + doodadtotal

                 print('Record #',records, 'Customer #',ID)
                 print(numwidgets, 'Widgets ordered @ $10.55---- $',widgettotal)
                 print(numgidgets, 'Gidgets ordered @ $7.30----$',gidgettotal)
                 print(numdoodads, 'Doodads orderd @ $5.25----$',doodadtotal)
                 print('Invoice total------------$',invoicetotal)


                 invoice_file.close()



    if (choice == 4):
                 break

    run_again = input('Would you like to run this program again?'
                      '(Enter y for yes or n for no): ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is necessarily that the lines from choice 2 don't get written to the file but that they don't get read as part of choice 3. The code in choice 3 will try to read the first four lines of the file and nothing else no matter what. You might instead want something like:

```
if choice == "3":
    invoice_file = open('invoices.txt', 'r')
    lines = invoice_file.readlines(4)
    records, num_widgets, num_gadgets, num_doodads = 0, 0, 0, 0
    while len(lines) == 4:
        records += 1
        num_widgets += 1
        # ...
        lines = invoice_file.readlines(4)

    # Do calculations, output, and close file
```